# Eclipse RCP - remove command from the popup

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a tool (which is built over Eclipse). In that there is a popup menu called "Edit Properties" if a object is right clicked. I need to hide this menu command. Provided that it should not be gets hided from the standard menu, should only be hide from the popup.

How to do this? Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: "Edit Properties" is a menu or a command? and what is the standard menu?

Comment: "Edit Properties" is a command. This command is available in both context menu(Right Click) and in the standard menu like File, Edit, View...

Comment: Is this a custom command you wrote or a generic command? If it is your command, then you probably added it by mistake to the popup menu using an org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point with a "popup:" prefix.

Comment: That's not a custom command. Requirement is to hide that command from popup menu. How to get control over the existing commands...?